# Ubuntu server WordPress connection error on plugins and themes

Tags: 18.04, server, wordpress

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server, with WordPress installed. Upon finishing the installation, I have connection error in the plugins page. At first it was only an error message from `plugin-install.php`.  After rebooting, 2 more error message occurred as shown below and I could not ping anything from my server. (100% packet loss with anything I pinged.) I tried editing the `/ect/hosts` file, and I tried to modify `php.ini` file (could not find extension=curl.so) but to no avail.

Any ideas?

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/update.php on line 413

Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/update.php on line 693

Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 183
```

Attached is the log directory for reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBOvW.jpg)

The faillog is only a series of ^@ code in it.

Comment: Can you check the `/var/log/apche2/error` log file for your site and see if there’s a more specific error message? There’s not enough to work with based on the generic message you’ve shared.

Comment: I am using Nginx, so I don't have apache2 installed

Comment: Regardless, there should be a log file of some sort with something specific describing the error. If there is no log, then any suggested solutions would be little more than wild guesses that will likely result in little more than wasted time 

Comment: I have attached an image of the log directory, maybe it might help in deciding which file to check?